# gridspec with subfigures that have fixed aspect ratio

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I use mpl_toolkits.basemap (Basemap) which returns figures with fixed aspect ratios. I like to group a few plots from Basemap into one figure.

**The problem:** Basemap in combination with gridspec creates large white spaces between the subplots.

**The Question:** How can I remove the white space between subplots in this case? Alternativly, can I let the subplots fill the figure from top towards the bottom and then crop the left over white space?

**A requirement** is that the width of the figure (e.g. fig_width=0.4) is a fraction of an A4 page (i.e. A4_width=21cm), while the height of the figure needs to be large in order to let Basemap scale the plot freely.

Below are two examples, (a) one with large y-axis-length and (b) one where the y-axis-length is chosen manually to approximate the desired result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

def plot_figure(fig):
    x = np.arange(20)
    y = np.arange(10)
    Z = np.outer(y, x)
    nrow,  ncol  = 0, 0 # counter for axis position from gridspec
    nrows, ncols = 6, 4 # number of gridspec columns and rows
    ax = {}
    for n in xrange(11):
        # use gridspec for the wspace and hspace options
        gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows = nrows, ncols = ncols)
        gs.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
        ax[str(n).zfill(2)] = plt.subplot(gs[nrow, ncol])
        # plot with Basemap
        width, height, lat_ts, lat_0, lon_0 = 2.5e6, 1.2e6, 5., 5., 10.
        m = Basemap(width = width, height = height, resolution = 'c', projection = 'laea',
                    lat_ts = lat_ts, lat_0 = lat_0, lon_0 = lon_0)
        X,  Y  = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        mX, mY = m(X, Y)
        parallels = m.drawparallels(np.arange(-10.,30.,5.), labels=[1,0,0,0] if ncol == 0 else [0,0,0,0])
        meridians = m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-20.,20.,5.), labels=[0,0,1,0] if nrow == 0 else [0,0,0,0])
        cf = m.contourf(mX, mY, Z);
        # go through the axis coordinates
        if ncol < ncols - 1 :
            ncol += 1
        else :
            ncol = 0
            nrow += 1

A4_width, A4_height = 21 / 2.54, 29.5 / 2.54
```

**(a)** Now with large y-axis-length (desired, but wrong):

```
fig_width, fig_height = 0.85, 1.0
f1 = plt.figure(figsize=( fig_width * A4_width, fig_height * A4_height))
plot_figure(f1)
plt.savefig('f1.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

tight_layout seems not to work here

```
# gs.tight_layout(f1)
```

raises error:

> 'UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so its results might be incorrect. warnings.warn("This figure includes Axes that are not "'

**(b)** With manually set y-axis-length (undesired, however the result is OK):

```
fig_width, fig_height = 0.85, 0.4
f2 = plt.figure(figsize=( fig_width * A4_width, fig_height * A4_height))
plot_figure(f2)
plt.savefig('f2.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong with approach (b) if the result looks like you want it. Can you be more precise about the requirement you have?

Comment: Approach (b) is OK, however I then have to look at the figure several times until I get an approximate minimum (or even amount in x and y) of white space between the individual subplots. I am mainly curious if there is an other way to handle fixed aspect ratios, that requires less manual adjustment.

Comment: So essentially, `fig_height` may be any value between 0 and 1 and the problem is that you don't want to find out that value yourself?! Is `tight_layout` not working or is it just throwing a warning? Is the result you would get with normal (not Basemap) plots together with `tight_layout` meating those requirements? Do you always have the same grid (like 3x4) or does that change? Do you always have the same aspect images or are should a solution be independent of the images' aspect? I don't have an idea for a solution right now, but those are important things a potential answerer should know.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to provide all helpful informations. [1] yes, `fig_height` might be a value between 0 and 1, 1 would mean the figure has A4 height, and 0 then no height. [2] it seems that `tight_layout` does not always raise that warning, however it only affects the last subplot if run like `gs.tight_layout(f1)` [3] I couldn't force `aspect='equal'` with gridspec and contourf. However equal aspect ratio is an requirement. [4] Grid size varies, n x m, depends on the size of the area I want to look at.

Comment: [5] The aspect ratio of each subplot is the same, the aspect ratio between figures might change, however is always "equal", 1 degree latitude against 1 degree longitude. [6] I might want to use an other, still fixed, aspect ratio later, where I have latitude against meter. [7] I fix my width to the A4 width in order to have readable labels when the figure is included in a text. (The tikz format would maybe solve my problems, I just had no time to learn/understand it and then to get it running). [8] error: it seems that my figure width does not work as I intended. Can't look at it right now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to automatically fill a given space non-homogeneous with images that have a fixed aspect ratio.

The solution is therefore – disappointingly – manual iteration:

1. Plot your images
2. Check whether you like how it looks
3. it looks good?

   - if not: update your settings and back to 1.
   - if yes: you're done.

Comment: There is a library now (https://proplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which can handle automatic spacing with geographic projections (and other fixed-aspect ratio plots)